# Cannot implicitly convert type in my task

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DateTime property I am trying to set. However I am receiving an error that says

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'ProjectName.Core.Entities.MyClassName'"

How do I assign my variable back to it's property?

Here is the class with the Property I am trying to set

```
public class MyClassName
{
   public DateTime? MyDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my task where I am trying to assign the variable back to the property but am receiving the above message. What am I missing?

```
public async Task<MyClassName> GetMyDateDateAsync()
 {
  var myVar = (from x in _dbDbContext.Table select x.Column).Max();          
     return myVar;
 }
```

Comment: You would have to do this in 2 steps. Get the max value and then create a new objec t of type MyClassName and return it. return new MyClassName{MyDateTime = myVar};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have type mismatch between `myVar` and returned type.

One option would be to just create an instance:

```cs
public async Task<MyClassName> GetMyDateDateAsync()
{     
    return new MyClassName
    {
        MyDateTime = await  _dbDbContext.Table.MaxAsync(x => x.Column)
    };
}
```

If `_dbDbContext.Table` stores the `MyClassName` and you want to return one with max `MyDateTime` then try:

```
public async Task<MyClassName> GetMyDateDateAsync()
{
    return await _dbDbContext.Table
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Column)
        .First();
}
```

Comment: Also using the suggested approach the return has the same error of not being able to convert the datatype (The error mentioned above in the question) thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dev101684 eve the first one?

Comment: @Dev101684 ok *what* type is being returned from a query to `_dbDbContext.Table`? Its really important to realize that use of `var` is static inferred typing and not dynamic typing. Approach one probably has to be chained to another `.Select()` query to create the MyClassName obj

Comment: After working with the code a little longer received the correct response. Thank you!